# Is 555 timer good to generate 20MHz clock?

Tags: clock, timer

I am looking for a way to generate 10 to 20MHz TTL-compatible clock signal. I used something like microchip unit to produce clock signal before in school but I didn't use any other way to generate clock pulses. Someone suggests to use 555 timer but I one of the handbook I have told that 555 timer won't support clock frequency as high as 20MHz. Is that true? I need a pretty stable clock signal which will be run for more than 60 hours continuously once it is on. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's too fast for a 555, if you don't need to vary the frequency probably a crystal oscillator module like this one is easiest http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ECS-2200BX-200/XC1188-ND/827295

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. It sound like what I am looking for. From the spec, it said that the output is TTL compatible, so does it output square wave? Is oscillator stable and long life? Thanks.

Comment: It's a square wave minus a small rise/fall time you'll get with anything, there's a diagram in the datasheet link. Yes it'll be quite stable (exact numbers are in there as well) and I'd expect it to last for years.

Comment: @PeterJ, Sorry Peter, but I posted an answer along the sames lines as your comment. I was already typing it in when I saw your comment...

Comment: @Ricardo, no problems, am just on my way out the door and didn't have time to write an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is a **crystal oscillator module** like [this one from Farnel](http://uk.farnell.com/epson/sg531p20mhz/crystal-oscillator-20mhz/dp/1216196) or [the one PeterJ recommended](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ECS-2200BX-200/XC1188-ND/827295). They come in 4 pin packages like in the images below. They will generate your clock for you.

[image: Crystal oscillator image]
[image: Crystal oscillator image]
[image: Crystal oscillator image]

Both modules mentioned have tolerances of 50 ppm and operate at 5V.

It's not to be confused with regular 2 pin **crystal** like this below. Those are part of the circuitry of external clocks for MCUs, for example.

[image: Crystal oscillator]

Comment: To avoid confusion, the two-pin device should just be called a crystal - with additional parts, the crystal becomes part of an oscillator.

Comment: @PeterBennett Right. I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Note that Farnell tends to be pretty expensive. You often can find cheaper parts at [Digikey](http://digikey.com).